# A question about systems of nonlinear equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, cluster-algebra

Recently, I read a book on cluster algebra and come across a problem that could finally be reduced to a problem of solving a system of nonlinear equations.

The question is:

> Give $b_{12},b_{13} , b_{14},b_{23},b_{24},b_{34}\in \mathbb{C}$   satisfying $b_{12}b_{34}+b_{14}b_{23}-b_{13}b_{24}=0$.
>
> Solve the system of  nonlinear equations:
>
> $\begin{cases}  a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21}=b_{12}\\
>   a_{11}a_{23}-a_{13}a_{21}=b_{13}\\
>   a_{11}a_{24}-a_{14}a_{21}=b_{14}\\
>      a_{12}a_{23}-a_{13}a_{22}=b_{23}\\
>      a_{12}a_{24}-a_{14}a_{22}=b_{24}\\
>      a_{13}a_{24}-a_{14}a_{23}=b_{34}\\ 
> \end{cases}$

I want to solve the above system of nonlinear equations, but I don't know anything about systems of nonlinear equations.

Is there a solution to the system of equations? If so, what is the relationship between the solutions?

If anyone can give me some reference books or methods, I would be very grateful!

Comment: Your issue looks connected with grassmannian space G(2,4) (set of 2D planes in the 4D space) as can be seen [here](https://www.imprs-mis.mpg.de/fileadmin/imprs/imprs-ringvorlesung-2018_may-08.pdf), the first constraint being known as Klein surface. But with real (not complex) coordinates.

Comment: Thanks! It is just the problem.  I  will  read it.

Comment: I had never heard about "cluster algebra". In the Wikipedia article, they mention indeed connections with grassmannian spaces and Plücker coordinates.

Comment: @Jean Marie  I am a new graduate student. I've just started studying cluster algebra. In fact , this problem is about the motivation of cluseter algebra. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $b_{12}$ is nonzero.

If you assume that $$\left[\begin{array}{cc} a_{11}&a_{12}\\ a_{21}&a_{22}\end{array}\right]$$ is $b_{12}$ times an identity matrix, then you will find that you get linear equations to solve for the other entries.

Thinking of the entries $a_{ij}$ as a $2\times 4$ matrix, you can multiply it on the left by a two-by-two matrix with determinant 1, and this will give you all the other possible solutions.

If $b_{12}$ is zero, you can use a somewhat similar approach, first assuming that $a_{21}$ and $a_{22}$ are zero, and then, again, getting general solutions by multiplying by an invertible two-by-two matrix.